# Python netcdf - Monthly median over the all time period of daily data

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF file `input.nc`. This file represents nearly 18 years of data sampled every 4 days. From this file, I would like to calculate the monthly median value over the all time period. So the output file should only contain 12-time steps.

I am using the following code:

```
import xarray as xr
os.chdir(inbasedir)
data = xr.open_dataset('input.nc')
monthly_data = data.resample(freq='m', dim ='time', how = 'median')
monthly_data.to_netcdf("test.nc")
```

Unfortunately when I look at the output file, my code has done the median value for each month of the all time serie and I end up with more than 200 values. How can I change my code, in order to calculate the 12 monthly medians over the all time period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [groupby](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.groupby.html#xarray.Dataset.groupby) method:

```
monthly_data = data.groupby('time.month').median()
```

There are some good examples of how to use xarray with timeseries data here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html